# How do I change PSI-Probe to not use 1E8 for memory usage?

Tags: java-8, tomcat8, probe

The [PSI-Probe](https://github.com/psi-probe)  project provides statistics for Java programs deployed in a Tomcat server. One of its services is memory usage.

The 3.0.0.RC1 version of PSI-Probe I'm using shows usage in an unpleasant format, using "E" notation, like 7E8 for 700,000,000.

[image]

I've looked all over but can't find a configuration option for this.  Is there a configuration to get the axis to display values like "700,000,000"?

Thanks,

Jerome.